# All-inclusive selector for button (as an alternative to :button)

Tags: jquery, selector

I am trying to select ALL buttons in a form, which includes the `reset` and `submit` elements.  My current selector is this:

`:button, [type=\"submit\"], [type=\"reset\"]`

However, it is not working with `reset`.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
        <form>

        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <select>
            <option>hello</option>
            <option>hi
            </option>
            <option></option>
        </select>
        <textarea></textarea>
        <input type="checkbox" name="hi" value="hi" />
        <input type="radio" name="test" value="hi" />
        <input type="radio" name="test" value="hello" />
        <input type="radio" name="test" />
        <input type="button" />
        <button></button>
        <input type="reset" />
        <input type="submit" />

    </form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("form").submit(function() {

    var shouldSubmit = true;

    $(this).children(":input:not(:button, [type=\"submit\"], [type=\"reset\"])").each(function() {

        if ($(this).val() == "")
        {
            shouldSubmit = false;
            return shouldSubmit;
        }

    });

    if ($("input:checkbox").length > 0)
    {
        if ($("input:checkbox:checked").length == 0)
            shouldSubmit = false;
    }

    if ($("input:radio").length > 0)
    {
        if ($("input:radio:checked").length == 0)
            shouldSubmit = false;
    }

    if (shouldSubmit == false)
        alert("All form fields must be filled out.");

    return shouldSubmit;

});

});
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and a jsFiddle.net example if possible.

Comment: Here's a fiddle that outputs all three buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/FkfSU/

Comment: See my edits.  I included the code.

Comment: seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/xqg7p/

Comment: I don't see a problem with your code. Reduce the error to a few lines and try to reproduce the problem with as little code as possible. Please.

Comment: On further inspection, I really don't see a problem with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/bTj4n/ The reset button is indeed part of the selector

Comment: Hm.  Now it's working.  I guess it was probably just some mis-type on my part.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not reproducible and probably due to a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this jquery selector :

```
$('button, button[type="submit"], button[type="reset"]')
```

Comment: I'm looking for an all-inclusive selector, so I would also need to select a normal button.

Comment: I don't understand. If you want to select a normal button, why you don't use $('button') selector ?

Comment: Because I would like it to be ALL-INCLUSIVE, so it can select a normal button, reset button, and submit button.

Comment: Yes with the $('button') selector, you can select a normal button, reset button, and submit button

Comment: Not according to the jQuery spec.

Comment: I updated my answer, is it good ? But, I have never heard of this spec.